# Normalization of an imported CSV dataset which contains delimited columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-normalization

I have a delimited dataset which imports into PostgreSQL 10.4. This dataset has some columns which also contains delimited dataset. I want to normalize this database.

I prepared an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c619c/1) for easier understanding what I want to achieve:

```sql
/*
    The purpose of this fiddle is to normalize a csv import as much as possible,
    stripping off the duplicate rows,
    referencing them from a normalized table (e.g. one tag only presented once).

    Indexing is left out for the simplicity of these examples.
*/

-- In real world, this is a TEMPORARY table,
-- automatically deletes itself after the session,
-- only supplementing the csv import process.
-- There's no data integrity checks here (like UNIQUE, NOT NULL, etc.).
CREATE TABLE csv_import_temp (
    url       text, -- only one url per blog post allowed
    category  text, -- only one category per blog post allowed
    tags      text, -- tags can be many or even NULL for a blog post
    upvote    int,  -- only one upvote per blog post allowed (updated frequently)
    title     text, -- title is unique for every blog post (out of normalization attempt)
    body      text  -- body is unique for every blog post (out of normalization attempt)
);

CREATE TABLE post_single (
    url       text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    category  text NOT NULL,
    -- we should reference tags elsewhere
    upvote    int DEFAULT 0,
    title     text NOT NULL,
    body      text NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (url)
);

CREATE TABLE post_tags (
    url   text NOT NULL,
    tags  text,

    FOREIGN KEY (url) REFERENCES post_single(url) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- We will create a view called by a parameterized query,
-- for the API request (like: https://example.com/api/v1/single/:url).
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_api AS
    SELECT
        p.url,
        p.category,
        array_agg(DISTINCT t.tags) AS tags,
        p.upvote,
        p.title,
        p.body
    FROM post_single p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN post_tags t ON (p.url = t.url)
    GROUP BY
        p.url,
        p.category,
        p.upvote,
        p.title,
        p.body
;
```

`csv_import_temp` looks like this after `COPY`:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║     url      ║ category  ║        tags         ║ upvote  ║     title      ║     body      ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ first-post   ║ news      ║ (null)              ║ 11      ║ My first post  ║ Hello, World! ║
║ second-post  ║ news      ║ first               ║ (null)  ║ Title 2        ║ Body 2!       ║
║ third-post   ║ another   ║ first;second;third  ║ 2       ║ Title 3        ║ Body 3!       ║
║ last-post    ║ last      ║ first;fourth        ║ 139     ║ Title 4        ║ Body 4!       ║
║ fifth-post   ║ another   ║ (null)              ║ (null)  ║ Title 5        ║ Body 5!       ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

In the `post_tags` table I only want to store the tags and referencing a foreign key to `post_single` table's `url` column:

```
╔══════════════╦════════╗
║     url      ║  tags  ║
╠══════════════╬════════╣
║ second-post  ║ first  ║
║ third-post   ║ first  ║
║ third-post   ║ second ║
║ third-post   ║ third  ║
║ last-post    ║ first  ║
║ last-post    ║ fourth ║
╚══════════════╩════════╝
```

And here comes my confusion. This `tags` are duplicate values, right? Is there any way to create a table where a tag only presented once (and because of that, it can be a unique key or use another column `pkey` with `serial` value)?

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ pkey  ║  tags  ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║    1  ║ first  ║
║    2  ║ second ║
║    3  ║ third  ║
║    4  ║ fourth ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

So for example, the `first` tag only presented once in the entire database and we should referencing it's foreign key, when we creating a view for final API output with the `view_api` VIEW, where `tags[]` column is an array:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║    url      ║ category  ║        tags[]         ║ upvote  ║  title   ║  body  ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ third-post  ║ another   ║ {first,second,third}  ║      2  ║ Title 3  ║ Body 3 ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Or eventually this design won't gain anything (disk space, execution speed), because my already made normalization attempt is good enough?

**Edit:**

In case of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c619c/1) is not executing, here is a screenshot:

[image: sqlfiddle screenshot]

Comment: What is your question again? Do you want a query to generate a list of distinct tags? In MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: I'm using Postgres. My confusion comes from when you see `post_tags` table, you see `first` tag multiple times at the 2nd, 3rd and last post, (because many blog post can have the same tag). However If I normalizing the tags table with `SELECT DISTINCT` (thanks for the tip), a tag will only be presented once in the table is a unique value, but I need a key for every unique tag and referencing the tags for every blog post by their key(s), but eventually I didn't done anything useful, right?

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat. Personally I see nothing wrong with resolving the non-atomic (delimited in one field) data with a table containing just {url, tag}. Yes, there will be duplicate tags, but this isn't an issue as long as you don't have duplicates on both tag and url. You could of course create a surrogate key and another table to hold the tag values as you suggested, but it's not required (then you'll just have those "duplicates" on the surrogate key).

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se with a subrow appearing more than once in a table or DB. Replacing values by other values that are ids leaves the same patterns of values & is not part of normalization. Yes, your "already made normalization attempt is good enough" & is one of the transformations people include under "normalization to 1NF". But a proper justification requires a presentation of normalization (to 1NF & to higher NFs). See a textbook. stanford.edu has a free online course. PS Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Please clarify via edits, not comments.